# Start and End time using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I need to enter the start date, start time, end date and end time in my asp.net MVC application. date fields are textbox and time fields are dropdown.

How can i fill the time dropdowns using jquery.?

Also i need to restrict the user to select the invalid time periods. For ex.: when  the user selects 9:00 AM in start time dropdown, the end time should not be 08:00 AM of the same day. 
i.e. the user should not select the end time lesser than start time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use just textboxes for the time input and combine that with the [jQuery Mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) (ie; "99:99") and a [custom regex validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) using [this jQuery Validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin. The custom validator would not only ensure that the value given for the times are valid times but that the ending time is greater than the beginning time (if your using 24 hour its much easier).

Comment: I have used jQuery.ptTimeSelect for time selection.
The sample for this is at http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For picking dates you can try to use [Date Range picker](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

Comment: Hi, I need to display along with the time as you can see while adding an event in google calendar